# Actualizar BD MYSQL desde ORACLE

Tags: mysql, oracle

Estoy trabajando con MYSQL y ORACLE, en donde lo que hago es realizar una consulta a ORACLE y posteriormente cargar esta información en MYSQL. Todo funciona bien y logro cargar la información en MYSQL, pero el problema que tengo, es que si hay un campo vacío en ORACLE, me borra el campo con datos en MYSQL.

**CONSULTA ORACLE**

```
SELECT 
RUT, 
NOM1, 
NOM2, 
AP_PATERNO, 
MATERNO, 
CARRERA, 
EMAIL
FROM PERS
```

**CONSULTA MYSQL**

```
UPDATE 
alumno 
SET 
nombres = '$row[NOM1] $row[NOM2]', 
apellidos = '$row[AP_PATERNO] $row[AP_MATERNO]', 
codigo = '$row[CARRERA]', 
correo = '$row[EMAIL]' 
WHERE rut = '$row[RUT]'
```

Lo que quisiera saber es si hay alguna manera de validar que el UPDATE no actualice un campo en MYSQL, en los casos que la información extraída de ORACLE sea la misma o que el campo este vacío.

Agradecería si alguien me pueda orientar a resolver esto.

Comment: ¿Tal vez validando los criterios que mencionás en el WHERE?

Comment: Me podrías indicar mas o menos como seria la validación, estoy un poco perdido...

Comment: Si el campo esta vacio, obviamente va a vaciar el campo en sql server.. vos hablas de no actualizar las filas si hay un campo vacio, o decis solo ese campo?

Comment: seria una validación para cada campo..

Comment: Que campo es el que dices que te borra?, si puedes ser mas especifico en tu problema para poder ayudarte mejor, recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta la veces que sean necesarias.

Comment: Esto ocurre con cualquiera de los campos. Ejemplo: si extraigo NOM1 de ORACLE, esta se debe cargar en Nombres en MYSQL. Y aquí ocurre el problema, ya que si NOM1 no trae información y Nombres si tiene información, lo que hace el UPDATE es cargar el vacío y borrar la información de Nombres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes validar y evitar que se actualicen los campos en `MySQL` en los casos donde la información extraída de Oracle sea la misma o el campo esté vacío. Una forma de hacerlo es usar una cláusula `CASE` en la consulta `UPDATE` de `MySQL`.

```
UPDATE alumno 
SET 
nombres = CASE 
            WHEN '$row[NOM1] $row[NOM2]' = '' OR '$row[NOM1] $row[NOM2]' IS NULL OR CONCAT(nombres, ' ', apellidos) = '$row[NOM1] $row[NOM2]' 
            THEN nombres 
            ELSE '$row[NOM1] $row[NOM2]' 
          END, 
apellidos = CASE 
              WHEN '$row[AP_PATERNO] $row[AP_MATERNO]' = '' OR '$row[AP_PATERNO] $row[AP_MATERNO]' IS NULL OR CONCAT(apellidos, ' ', nombres) = '$row[AP_PATERNO] $row[AP_MATERNO]' 
              THEN apellidos 
              ELSE '$row[AP_PATERNO] $row[AP_MATERNO]' 
            END, 
codigo = CASE 
           WHEN '$row[CARRERA]' = '' OR '$row[CARRERA]' IS NULL OR codigo = '$row[CARRERA]' 
           THEN codigo 
           ELSE '$row[CARRERA]' 
         END, 
correo = CASE 
           WHEN '$row[EMAIL]' = '' OR '$row[EMAIL]' IS NULL OR correo = '$row[EMAIL]' 
           THEN correo 
           ELSE '$row[EMAIL]' 
         END
WHERE rut = '$row[RUT]'
```

En cada cláusula `CASE`, se verifica si el valor extraído de `Oracle` es `NULL` o si es igual al valor actual en `MySQL`.

Si se cumple alguna de estas condiciones, el campo no se actualizará y se mantendrá su valor actual. De lo contrario, se actualizará con el nuevo valor extraído de `Oracle`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función [**`IF()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp) de MySQL para validar si el valor obtenido de la consulta a Oracle es una cadena vacía o no, así:

```
nombres = IF('$row[NOM1] $row[NOM2]' = '', nombres, '$row[NOM1] $row[NOM2]'),
```

Aquí digo que si la cadena está vacía, entonces el valor existente en la tabla se mantiene usando el nombre de la columna `nombres` (o sea, se mantiene sin ningún cambio), de lo contrario, se asigna ese valor a la columna correspondiente (`$row[NOM1] $row[NOM2]`), y así para cada una de tus columnas.

---

Aplicando el `IF()` a todas tus columnas, sería algo así:

```
UPDATE
alumno 
SET 
nombres = IF('$row[NOM1] $row[NOM2]' = '', nombres, '$row[NOM1] $row[NOM2]'),
apellidos = IF('$row[AP_PATERNO] $row[AP_MATERNO]' = '', apellidos, '$row[AP_PATERNO] $row[AP_MATERNO]'),
codigo = IF('$row[CARRERA]' = '', codigo, '$row[CARRERA]'),
correo = IF('$row[EMAIL]' = '', correo, '$row[EMAIL]')
WHERE rut = '$row[RUT]'
```